# Using toString for multiple JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, tostring

In my worker class, I have several methods that return double values. In my driver class I'm tasked with putting each return value into a corresponding `JTextField`. For example, I have a`getTotalTax` methods that returns the total taxes paid, and that number has to be put in a `JTextField` in currency format. I don't know how I'm supposed to use my `toString` method.

As it stands I call this in my driver class:

```
totalTaxField.setText(Report.toString());
```

And my toString class:

```
public String toString(){       
    return fmt1.format(getTotalTax());
}
```

EDIT:

Here's more code to help express my problem:

```
public double getTotalTax(){

        double totalTax = getTotalSales()*TAX_RATE;

        return totalTax;
    }

    public double getTotalSales(){

        double totalSales =
                getSalesLarge()+getSalesMedium()+getSalesSmall()+getSalesStick();

        return totalSales;
    }
```

Those are two methods in my worker class, I need to take the result of both of them and place them in two different `JTextFields` like so.

```
totalSalesField.setText(?);
totalTaxField.setText(?);
```

I need to use the `getString` function to somehow set the text to the text field.

Answer (score 1):

`toString` method is not a static method, so you should call it from a Report object like:

```
 Report report = new Report();//suppose this a valid declaration form a Report class.
 totalTaxField.setText(report.toString());
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing.
DailySales Report = new DailySales(largePizzaSales,mediumPizzaSales,smallPizzaSales,breadStickSales)
Probably should make it a lowercase r in report.

Comment: could you please post more code to describe your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear but it sounds like you need to convert a double into a string with currency formatting.

Who can do that with the following:

```
public String toString(){       
return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(getTotalTax());
```

}

Comment: Yes that's how I'm doing it.

My problem is that I have several JTextFields to fill, but they all need to be filled using the toString method.